# Does the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) support cpufreq as used by Python psutil?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, psutil, auto-keras

I am using the WSL (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) for machine learning projects. So I installed autokeras 1.0 on Python 3.6 which is based on the new tensorflow 2.0. However, all autokeras examples break with the psutil error message "NotImplementedError: can't find current frequency file".

So far, I found out that psutil is looking for a file named cpuinfo_cur_freq
for each cpu e.g. in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/. However, in that path I only have the files cpuinfo_max_freq and scaling_max_freq. As far as I understand, the files pstool is looking for are managed by the Linux cpufreq kernel infrastructure, which obviously is not active on my system.

So I wonder if WSL supports the Linux cpufreq infrastructure at all. I could imagine this to be difficult as it would have to be coordinated with the cpu management on the Windows host system. But if WSL does support it, I would like to learn, what I need to do to get it running.

I am not sure, if this is the right place to ask, but the platforms provided by Microsoft for WSL (GitHub and UserVoice) did not seem appropriate to me.

Comment: I'd consider filing an issue on Autokeras' GitHub, seems like a bug on their side more than on WSL's

Comment: Did you check the Github site to see if other people have asked the same thing? Besides, WSL is something that evloves all the time and the latest version WSL2 is far more powerful. Which version did you use, which Windows 10 version do you have?

Comment: I tried lots of Google queries but could not find anything - neither on their GitHub nor on the WSL docs. I don't have access to WSL2 yet because I am still on Windows 10 1903 (build 18362.418) and as far as I know WSL2 is only available on 1909 or via the insider previiew versions.

@GPhilo: I really don't think it can be an autokeras bug because they are very actively working on the new version. Therefore, someone else would have noticed that their standard examples fail due to a bug.

Comment: WSL does implement `lscpu`, but the "CPU MHz" and "CPU max MHz" seem to be static  values. So I think you're out of luck.